# Convert ASCII code to string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to create a char array based on a single ASCII code. The folowing code does not compile correctly, even though "num" is cast to a char:

```
//Returns the ASCII counterpart of a number, such as 41 = A, 42 = B, 43 = C, etc.
char numToASCII(int num) {
    char[] string = {(char)num, "\0"};
    return string;
}
```

For the task that I am given, it is very important that "string" be a character array/string and not a single char. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you are doing almost actually works... you need to use a char rather than a string for the null terminator: I think `char[] string = {(char)num, '\0'};` will compile...

Comment: but dont return that, it will be out of scope when you use it, either malloc something or pass in the memory

Comment: Quite a few things wrong with these three lines of code. Anyway, you can't return an array from a function in C. You could pass an array into the function to hold the string; do you really need a function for this? What about using a compound literal instead?

Comment: Thank you for that information, @DavidBowling. I was not aware that C functions can't return an array. With that in mind, I will have to use a compound literal.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do here, but you can also use `snprintf()` or `printf()` (if you're trying to print it to stdout).  You still need to provide space for the string though.  Something like `char s[2]; snprintf(&s[0], sizeof(s), "%c", num);`.  Also, note that 41 is not "A", 0x41 is "A". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array must be initialized to constant expressions and your function should return a pointer if you want to return an array.
If you just want to return a char, then use the following code instead:

```
char numToASCII(int num) {
    return (char)num;
}
```

If you want to return a string which contains the character, then you should use the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *numToASCII(int num) {
    /*
     * Use malloc to allocate an array in the heap, instead of using a
     * local array. The memory space of local array will be freed after
     * the invocation of numToASCII.
     */
    char *string = malloc(2);
    if (!string)
            return 0;
    string[0] = num;
    string[1] = 0;
    return string;
}
```

Use the `free()` function to free the space allocated by `malloc()`.

Comment: Now you have a memory leak.  And what if `malloc()` fails?

Comment: if malloc(2) fails you need to just go to bed... it isn't your day.. you program is about to crash or be eaten by the OOM monster

Comment: @GradyPlayer we don't know much about the environment here, but it may not be Linux.  I've seen systems that don't have a MMU, so you can't even trap access to a NULL pointer.  My point wasn't to be onerous, it's just to be careful about the assumptions being made.  That, and writing error free code is just hard. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
You want to find the character for the ASCII code,then try this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("\nEnter ASCII Code Number:\t");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\nASCII Value of %d: \t%c", num, num);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In this code it will get the ASCII code from the user and it will print the character for the ASCII code as default.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but pulling text from a file comes back as ascii, I needed a string and got around it by checking the string length, sorry for extra steps as I too am very new.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char firstbuff[yourchoice];
    char secondbuff[yourchoice];
    char sentence[yourchoice];
    int stringlenght;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    //Here add a means of counting the lines in the file as linecount
    for(int j = 0; j < linecount; j++)
    {
        fgets(firstbuff; 1000; fp);
 //get string length and use for loop to individually ascii copy as characters into array
        stringlength = strlen(firstbuff);
        for(int i = 0; i < stringlength; i++)
        {
           secondbuff[i] = (char)firstbuff[i];
        }
        //string concat
        strcat(sentence, secondbuff);
    }
    printf("%s\n", sentence);
    fclose(fp);
        
}
```

Comment: `strcat(sentence, secondbuff);` fails as `secondbuff` is not a _string_ (lacks an assigned null character).